# Myths about creatures/items/beings that talked with people or took away their problems?

Tags: myth-identification, mythical-creatures, folklore

Are there any myths about beings/items/creatures that talked with people in a friendly way? Almost as if the being was a therapist to the human or something? I can think of the caladrius that physically took away illness, but is there something like this that relieves more emotional/mental issues?

EDIT: I’m looking for any specific story from any mythology or legend or folklore. I’m just looking for a name or list of these stories if possible.

Comment: Do legends and fairy tales count here?

Comment: Yes, dozens, maybe hundreds.  Are you after anything specific?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Mauricio Yes, legends or fairy tales count. Is there a name of a specific legend/tale you could provide?

Comment: @Chenmunka I’m just looking for any name of one of these stories that I could further research. Or if there is some kind of list of names of ones you could think of that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like this would work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elves_and_the_Shoemaker ?